# Can't launch app as Docker container in VS 2017

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017, docker-compose

I installed *VS 2017* and *Docker for Windows*.
I created *.NET Core Web API* project in *VS 2017*, then added *Docker support* for this project. And trying to launch app as *Docker* container in **Debug** mode but it's failed for me with this error:

```
Cannot start service 'name': container 1b0c2da39774a91e508ae48476c1b918d7d6c863e2a1ad6ac105012998e0f22a 
encountered an error during Start: 
failure in a Windows system call: 
The compute system exited unexpectedly. (0xc0370106)
```

App is launched correctly only in **Release** mode but works bad.

Also I tried reinstall *Docker* and *VS 2017*, but it didn't help me. What do I do wrong?

Comment: Were you able to resolve those?  I have the same exact issue, only I it is the debug builds that work, release do not.  I also have this same error if I try to deploy the container locally using a volume line in my docker-compose.

Comment: Unfortunately, no

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when attempting to use a named volume in my docker compose file using Visual Studio 2017 with Docker CE 18.03.0-ce-win59 (16762) configured to run Windows containers on Windows 10.

Using the [Docker compose file documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) as reference, my docker-compose.yml file looked something like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  myserver:
    image: myserver
    build:
      context: .\myserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - folder:c:\folder

volumes:
  folder:
```

This would only work when I built ran a debug session inside of Visual Studio 2017.  Attempting to start a release build in Visual Studio with the debugger on or off would result in the error.  Attempting to bring the container up from the command line using "docker-compose up" also resulted in the error.

I managed to get it working by switching to a bind mount instead.  I created a folder on my local machine "c:\folder" and then changed my docker-compose.yml to:

```
version: '3'

services:
  myserver:
    image: myserver
    build:
      context: .\myserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - c:\folder:c:\folder
```

This resolved the error for me regardless of the method used to bring the container up.